# Custom navigation tabs disappears in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a custom navigation tabs in HTML, SCCS and JQuery. This is my code in HTML:

```
<div class="shortcut-nav-wrapper">
    <div class="shortcut-tab shortcut-tab-active" data-tab="all">
        <p>All</p>
    </div>
    <div class="shortcut-tab" data-tab="tab1">
        <p>Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="shortcut-tab" data-tab="tab2">
        <p>Tab 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="shortcut-tab" data-tab="tab3">
        <p>Tab 3</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="all">
test1
</div>
<div class="tab1 tab-hide">
test2
</div>
<div class="tab2 tab-hide">
test3
</div>
<div class="tab3 tab-hide">
test4
</div>
```

And this is my SCCS code for the tabs:

```
 .shortcut-tab {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        vertical-align: middle;

        p {
            color: black;
            margin-right: 56px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }

        &:hover {
            color: white;
            background-color: #D54606;
            border-radius: 25px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }

    .tab-hide {
        display: none;
    }
```

To switch from tab I have a function in JQuery like this:

```
$(".shortcut-tab").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("shortcut-tab-active").siblings()
            .removeClass("shortcut-tab-active");
        const classview = $(this).attr("data-tab");
        $(`.${classview}`).removeClass("tab-hide").siblings()
            .addClass("tab-hide");
    });
```

The styling and everything is working fine. The problem is when I switch from **tab** the navigation bar disappears. After I press F5 the navigation bar is back.

I have made a Jsfiddle so you can see the behavior.

https://jsfiddle.net/cf20s43v/3/

How can I fix that the navigation does not disappears when I switch from tab?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you select all siblings, including the `.shortcut-nav-wrapper`, since it's also a sibling. It then adds the class `.tab-hide` and gets hidden. So all you have to do is wrap all your tab-divs into a separate div

```
<div>
    <div class="all">
    test1
    </div>
    <div class="tab1 tab-hide">
    test2
    </div>
    <div class="tab2 tab-hide">
    test3
    </div>
    <div class="tab3 tab-hide">
    test4
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v9we0u4s/